# Summarization of simple Q&A

Tags: parsing, nlp, summary, summarization

Is there a way to generate a one-sentence summarization of Q&A pairs?

For example, provided:

```
Q: What is the color of the car?
A: Red
```

I want to generate a summary as

```
The color of the car is red
```

Or, given

```
Q: Are you a man?
A: Yes
```

to

```
Yes, I am a man.
```

which accounts for both question and answer.

What would be some of the most reasonable ways to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to once work on solving the opposite problem, i.e. generating questions out of sentences from Wikipedia articles.

I used the Stanford Parser to generate parse trees out of all possible sentences in my training dataset.

e.g.

1. Go to http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/parser/index.jsp
2. Enter "The color of the car is red." and click "Parse".
3. Then look at the Parse section of the response. The first layer of that sentence is **NP VP** (noun phrase followed by a verb phrase).
   The second layer is **NP PP VBZ ADJP**.

I basically collected these patterns across 1000s of sentences, sorted them how common each patter was, and then used figured out how to best modify this parse tree to convert into each sentence in a different Wh-question (What, Who, When, Where, Why, etc)

You could you easily do something very similar. Study the parse trees of all of your training data, and figure out what patterns you could extract to get your work done. In many cases, just replacing the Wh word from the question with the answer would give you a valid albeit somewhat awkwardly phrases sentence.
e.g. "Red is the color of the car."

In the case of questions like "Are you a man?" (i.e. primary verb is something like 'are', 'can', 'should', etc), swapping the first 2 words usually does the trick - "You are a man?"

Answer (score 1):

I don't know any NLP task that explicitly handles your requirement.

Broadly, there are two kinds of questions. Questions that expect a passage as the answer such as definition or explain sort: `What is Ebola Fever`. The second type are fill in the blank which are referred to as `Factoid Questions` in the literature such as `What is the height of Mt. Everest?`. It is not clear what kind of question you would like to summarize. I am assuming you are interested in factoid questions as your examples refer to only them.

A very similar problem arises in the task of `Question Answering`. One of the first stages of this task is to generate query. In the paper: [An Exploration of the Principles Underlying
Redundancy-Based Factoid Question
Answering; Jimmy Lin 2007](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/~jimmylin/publications/Lin_TOIS2007.pdf), the author claims that better performance can be achieved by reformulating the query (see section 4.1) to the form more likely to appear in free text. Let me copy some of the examples discussed in the paper.

`1. What year did Alaska became a state?
 2. Alaska became a state ?x`

`1. Who was the first person to run the miles in less than four minutes?
 2. The first person to run the miles in less than four minutes was ?x`

In the above examples, the query in `1` is reformulated to `2`. As you might have already observed, `?x` is the blank that should be filled by the answer. This reformulation is carried out through a dozen hand-written rules and are built into the software tool discussed in the paper: `ARANEA`. All you have to do is to find the tool and use it, the paper is a good ten years old, I cannot promise you anything though :)

Hope this helps.